# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: magento-1.7, database, sql

I'm using Google API to generate store locator in my module. I've stored all the store addressed in a separate table and accessing that table through direct SQL query to match locations inputted by user from frontend. Here's my query:

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');      
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');         
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM ".$resource->getTableName('onibi_storelocator/store')." HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
      mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
      mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
      mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
      mysql_real_escape_string($radius));       

$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
```

This code works alright in my localhost but when run it on development server it generates error like this:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Comment: Your mysql database is down :)

Comment: The rest of the store is working alright so the database is getting accessed by the store. There seems to be some specific problem with this only.

Comment: the rest runs through a PDO connection, how do you fire the query?

Comment: I have edited the code to include how i am firing the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution if anyone is interested. The SQL is supposed to be written in a different manner. Here is what worked for me:

```
// Search the rows in the markers table
$select = $readConnection->select()
    ->from(
        array('os' => $resource->getTableName('your_table')),
        array(
            'address', 'name', 'lat', 'lng',
            'distance' => new Zend_Db_Expr("( 3959 * acos( cos( radians({$center_lat}) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians({$center_lng}) ) + sin( radians({$center_lat}) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )")
        )
    )
    ->having("distance < ?", $radius)
    ->limit(20)
    ->order('distance');

$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($select);
```

Comment: You don't escape the input in from(), so this might be vulnerable to MySQL Injection...

Answer (score 5):

`mysql_real_escape_string` needs a database connection opened with `mysql_connect` to retrieve the current MySQL charset and properly escape the input based on this charset.

Magento uses PDO, therefore you can't use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Take a look on how Magento works with the Database, as a hint:

```
$readConnection->fetchAll('SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE a = ?', array($some_var));
```

PDO escapes everything correct and helps you to avoid security issues.

Please also consult the PHP manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: using the method of `$readConnection->fetchAll`returns nothing from database.

Comment: Is the SQL-Code correct? `$readConnection->fetchAll()` is actually `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::fetchAll()`. `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::query()` and `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::_prepareQuery()` take care of the bind-parameters.